# System.exit(0) does not prevent finally being called when have a SecurityManager.checkExit throw an exception

Tags: java

I have a problem with `System.exit(0);`.
When I tried the below code the output was nothing because of `System.exit(0);`:

```
String number = "12345M";
try {
    System.exit(0);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception caught");
} finally {
    System.out.println("inside finally");
}
```

But when I tried this below code:

```
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
    @Override
    public void checkExit(int status) {
        throw new ThreadDeath();
    }
});

try {
    System.exit(0);
} finally {
    System.out.println("I am  finally block");
}
```

The output was:

> I am finally block

Can someone please explain this different behavior?

Comment: If the System.exit() is prevented from do it's job you should expect it doesn't prevent the finally from being called.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because `exit` was prevented by the `ThreadDeath` exception (which is not one you should be throwing yourself btw):

> SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its checkExit method doesn't allow exit with the specified status.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)

Note that you should throw a `SecurityException` to prevent exit e.g.:

```
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
    @Override
    public void checkExit(int status) {
        throw new SecurityException("Not allowed.");
    }
});

try {
    System.exit(0);
} catch(SecurityException e) {
    System.out.println("Exit failed.");
} finally {
    System.out.println("I am finally block");
}
System.out.println("Program still running");
```

Output:

```
Exit failed.
I am finally block
Program still running
```

Answer (score 4):

When you call `System.exit()` without overriding the `checkExit()` method, the JVM is halted at that point and finally is not called.

However, when you do override the `checkExit()` method, the exception is thrown and finally is called.

Answer (score 3):

[Quoting](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/java_lang_securitymanager.htm):

> The java.lang.SecurityManager class allows applications to implement a security policy. It allows an application to determine, before performing a possibly unsafe or sensitive operation, what the operation is and whether it is being attempted in a security context that allows the operation to be performed. The application can allow or disallow the operation.

In the above code the checkExit determines whether the operation is allowed to operate and normally would work and thus exit. Since an exception is thrown, the operation is thus determined unsafe and is prevented from execution.

Please refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_exit.htm

Answer (score 2):

`System.exit(0);` is a called, it will call Runtime.exit subsequently and in it, it will check for if a SecurityManager is attached. 
If one is attached it will execute the checkExit method.

see the code in `Runtime.exit`:

```
public void exit(int status) {
    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (security != null) {
        security.checkExit(status);
    }
    Shutdown.exit(status);
}
```

So in your code the system actually does not exit when you call `System.exit(0);`, because you throw an exception in `SecurityManager.checkExit`

The `Shutdown.exit(status);` is never called and the VM is not stopped and it will continue to execute whatever statements and then it will reach the end of main method and terminate.

Change you code like this and play around

```
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
                              @Override
                              public void checkExit(int status) {

                                  if(status == 0){
                                      System.out.println("Not going to finally");
                                  }else{
                                      throw new SecurityException();
                                  }

                              }
                          });

    try {
        System.exit(1);

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        System.out.println("I am  finally block");
    }

    System.out.println("System.exit(1) Didn't work ......");

}
```

have a look at [System.exit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) java doc and [Runtime.exit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit(int)) doc